# Deformation and strain tensor

Tags: stress-energy-momentum-tensor, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

While reading books of continuum mechanics I noticed that authors call some tensors deformation tensors and other strain tensors.

My doubt is: why is right and left Cauchy-Green tensors commonly called deformation tensors while Lagrangian tensor is called strain tensor if the components of all these tensors are strain measures?

Comment: The right Cauchy-Green tensor $C$ is frame dependent, and the left Cauchy-Green tensor is $B$ is frame independent. See "https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Continuum_mechanics/Objectivity_in_kinematics"

Comment: The Cauchy-Green tensors are not strain measures.  They do not reduce to the infinitesimal strain tensor in the limit of small displacements.  However, the CG tensor minus the identity tensor divided by 2 is a strain tensor, and does reduce to the infinitesimal strain tensor in the limit of small displacements.

Comment: @ChetMiller Both CG tensor and Lagrangian tensor are composed of strain measures plus the product of strain measures if you expand the terms. I don't think reducing to infinitesimal strain tensor is important to answer this question, because the infinitesimal strain tensor is a special case of Lagrangian tensor and not a definition of what is strain and what is not.

Comment: If the CG tensor is expanded in terms of derivatives of the displacements, there will be terms like $(1+\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}$) which certainly is not a strain, and, for which, the 1 in the equation does not contribute to the stress.  Only the displacement gradient terms contribute to the stress.  And,, in the absence of deformation, the CG tensor reduces to the identity tensor, which certainly doesn't represent a strain.